# Vercel deployment fails "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'document')"

Tags: npm, deployment, next.js, vercel

I'm building a ReactJS/NextJS website and I was going to deploy it online using Vercel.
During the build I have some warnings as this one:
`warning package-lock.json found. Your project contains lock files generated by tools other than Yarn. It is advised not to mix package managers in order to avoid resolution inconsistencies caused by unsynchronized lock files. To clear this warning, remove package-lock.json.`
But then I get this fatal error, saying it can't read properties of undefined.
[image]
I'm not sure where to look at, something worth noticing is when I run `yarn run build` on my **local machine**, it does successfully compile as shown below
[image]

It's my first try experimenting with this tech so any hint would be appreciated! 
Thanks

Comment: Is the code a public repository?

Comment: @paulogdm yes you can find it here! https://github.com/StefanSpeterDev/blog-ReactJS-NextJS-Tailwind